# iOS: How to get a proper Month name from a number?

Tags: ios, numbers, nsdateformatter

I know that the NSDateformatter suite of functionality is a boon for mankind, but at the same time it is very confusing to me. I hope you can help me out.

Somewhere in my code, there is an int representing a month. So: 1 would be January, 2 February, etc.

In my user interface, I would like to display this integer as proper month name. Moreover, it should adhere to the locale of the device.

Thank you for your insights

In the mean time, I have done the following:

```
int monthNumber = 11
NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", monthNumber];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
[formatter release];
```

is this the way to do it? It seems a bit wordy.

Comment: you could replace MMMM with LLLL

Answer (score 166, accepted):

Another option is to use the monthSymbols method:

```
int monthNumber = 11;   //November
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *monthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(monthNumber-1)];
```

Note that you'll need to subtract 1 from your 1..12 monthNumber since monthSymbols is zero-based.

Comment: Thanks! While the other answers are very useful as well, this one suits the best in my situation!

Comment: Documentation for monthSymbols: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: This actually works only with the English locale (and similar languages). It doesn't work with locales for languages that use cases, e.g. Slavic languages. `standaloneMonthSymbols` must be used.

Comment: Simplification: ```NSString *monthName = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] monthSymbols][monthNumber-1];```

Comment: Please, use standaloneMonthSymbols

Comment: what is the reverse procedure like month is "jun" and i get "6"

Comment: @EICaptain it's late but you can use `NSDateComponents` to get it.

Comment: How can I get it with another langage?

Comment: Use `[df shortMonthSymbols]` if you want short month names (Jan, Feb...).

Comment: (The progress from ObjC in 2010 to Swift in 2020 is hilarious. Probably 5-7 times less typing.)

Answer (score 51):

```
let monthName = DateFormatter().monthSymbols[monthNumber - 1]
```

Answer (score 24):

You can change the dateFormat of the NSDateFormatter. So to simplify your code:

```
int monthNumber = 11
NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", monthNumber];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
[dateFormatter release];
```

You should also set the locale once you init the date formatter.

```
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale]; // Or any other locale
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 13):

Best solution for this is , `standaloneMonthSymbols` method,

```
-(NSString*)MonthNameString:(int)monthNumber
{
    NSDateFormatter *formate = [NSDateFormatter new];

    NSArray *monthNames = [formate standaloneMonthSymbols];

    NSString *monthName = [monthNames objectAtIndex:(monthNumber - 1)];

    return monthName;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
NSUInteger i = <your month integer>;
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
// change locale if the standard is not what you want
NSArray *monthNames = [df standaloneMonthSymbols];
NSString *monthName = [monthNames objectAtIndex:(i - 1)];
[df release];
```

Answer (score 9):

Both answers from Anna Karenina and Carl doesn't work that well as they won't return month name in nominativ for some cultures. I suggest to use the proposed solution from Pascal, which solves this issue (by replacing `monthSymbols` with `standaloneMonthSymbols`)

Answer (score 8):

**In Swift 3.0**

```
    let monthNumber = 3
    let fmt = DateFormatter()
    fmt.dateFormat = "MM"
    let month = fmt.monthSymbols[monthNumber - 1]
    print(month)

    // result
   "March\n"
```

Comment: Better to use `standaloneMonthSymbols` for correct case in some languages

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.X**

`print((DateFormatter().monthSymbols[month-1].capitalized)) //month is int less than 12`

For Example:

`print((DateFormatter().monthSymbols[11-1].capitalized))`

**Output**

November

Answer (score 4):

**NSDate to NSString** *-> As Dateformat Ex:* **2015/06/24**

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateformate=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        [dateformate setDateFormat: @"yyyy/MM/dd"];
        NSString *date = [dateformate stringFromDate:selectedDate]; // Convert date to string
```

**NSDate to NSString** *-> As Dateformat Ex:* **2015 June 24, 1:02 PM**

```
        [dateformate setDateFormat:@"yyyy MMMM dd, h:mm a"];
        NSString *displayDate = [dateformate stringFromDate:selectedDate]; // Convert date to string
        NSLog(@"date :%@",date);
        NSLog(@"Display time = %@", displayDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

And with ARC :

```
+ (NSString *)monthNameFromDate:(NSDate *)date {
    if (!date) return @"n/a";
    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    return [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:([[df stringFromDate:date] integerValue] - 1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get rid of the release and re-allocation of the dateFormatter, cutting out a couple of lines, but that's all I see.