# iphone how can i get month name from month number?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS: How to get a proper Month name from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488373/ios-how-to-get-a-proper-month-name-from-a-number)

How can I get month name from month number?

I have month number like **02**, but would like the month as a string, in this case **February**.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488373/ios-how-to-get-a-proper-month-name-from-a-number

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int monthNumber = 11;
NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", monthNumber];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
[dateFormatter release];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
[formatter release];

NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDate);
```

Comment: should be [formatter release]; instead of second [dateFormatter release];

Comment: so it should! was just a cut and paste jobby :p

Comment: How can I get the month with another langage?

Comment: @Llg This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8253250/143979

Answer (score 3):

You can use the monthSymbols array in NSDateFormatter, and then access that array by the key of the month number

Comment: That's a tad unnecessary :p

Comment: why do you need to invent the wheel again =) NSDateFormatter has monthSymbols array

Comment: technically it would look a lot cleaner than the accepted answer