# Do you have to pay a licensing fee to program for iPhone/iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, licensing

My coworker and I were discussing our desire to write iPhone applications.  He seems to believe that there is a 100 dollar licensing cost to program for the iPHone? Does this sound correct?

I could imagine that they might charge you to use some tools that they developed for this purpose but that they wouldn't/couldn't charge you just to be able to program on the device.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others have pointed out:

1. You can signup as an Apple developer for free
2. The development IDE (Xcode) is free and available on every Mac.
3. You do need to register to publish your app on the App Store. The registration cost is $99 per year.
4. As of Xcode 7, you can install apps you've developed to your iOS device without paying a registration fee.

Also, keep this in mind:

1. If you are going to develop enterprise applications (i.e. your app is not going to be sold in the App Store), the registration cost is $299 per year.
2. There are some ancillary costs- mainly source control.
   I use Versions by Sofa.  The cost there is $53.

Hope that helps!

Comment: how do you upgrade to an enterprise account from a regular? Can apps be both in the app store and outside of it?

Comment: Moshe, both programs are separate.  Unfortunately, there's no way to upgrade from one to the other.  From Apple's perspective, you pay $99 for the privilege of posting your apps to the App store and $299 for the privilege of being able to develop internal company apps.  If you want both privileges, you have to pay for both.

Comment: It's now free with Xcode 7 (beta): https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Comment: If I want to build an application for my own device it asks me provisioning profile. How can I get one? is it free or that too chargeable?

Answer (score 6):

The tools are free, but you need to register with Apple. You can then do most of your development for free.

However, to test on a device (as opposed to simulator), or submit the app to the App Store, you need to pay a $100 fee. (Here is the iOS Developer Program's homepage: [iphone how can i get month name from month number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887712/iphone-how-can-i-get-month-name-from-month-number))

Also, since you are thinking of getting started, you should know that you must have a Mac to run the iOS developer tools.

Answer (score 6):

$99 is the price you have to pay to generate needed certificates to test your apps on your device(s) and to submit apps to the App Store. You can test and develop your apps for free on the iOS simulator, but I would highly discourage you from this as its just a simulator and not a real device.

Comment: Well, I don't know if I understand 100% what you mean.  You mean you can't test on a device without first paying the 100 dollars?

Comment: @Scott: Yep, you need a certificate to run your apps on your device. This certificate (amongst some others) is what you need to pay for

Comment: OK. I had never heard about this yet.  My friend and I were going back and debating on what we thought was the right answer but neither of us have done this before.

Answer (score 2):

The development environment including Xcode is all free.

You can develop in a simulator on your mac also for free. The only bit you need to pay for is the ability to sign your applications so they can get pushed to a device for the Appstore - its 99 USD.

Don't forget - they take a cut of any sales on the appstore if you charge for your application!

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I can see why they would do the registration fee, even if I don't like it...

Comment: Just to add clarification. After paying for the developer license - it allows you to sign applications with the certificate they issue to you. This is for putting applications on an iphone for testing then later for putting on the appstore.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is also a Apple University Program which allows you to install your applications to iPhone, iPad and iPod touch. It *seems* to me that if you're studying in a degree granting, higher education institution, as they say, and are capable of influencing the institution into starting an iOS teaching course, you could develop your iOS software for free and test it on real Apple mobile devices. If you're either not in such a school or have no way of influencing the staff, you're out of luck with free methods unless you mess with the iPhone itself.