# Set UISegmentedControl text programmatically from variable

Tags: ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UISegmentedControl` on my view using storyboard and the text is currently being set programatically using the following lines of code:

```
[segMonth setTitle:@"Month 1" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segMonth setTitle:@"Month 2" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

I also have a date function using this code which gets the number (1-12) of the current month:

```
// Date
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSString *strDate = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",now];
    NSArray *arr = [strDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSString *str;
    str = [arr objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *arr_my = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];

    NSInteger month = [[arr_my objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
//End Date
```

I'm trying to name the first segment the current month 'December' and the second segment the next month 'January'.

I have tried using the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
[segMonth setTitle:@"%d" forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segMonth setTitle:@"%d" forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Obviously that would also only give the number of the month, not the name..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488373/ios-how-to-get-a-proper-month-name-from-a-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen your code, that contains a very hard way to get a month from `NSDate` I know, this may not be the answer. But I am just asking you to check this code to know the correct way to get the month or day or time or anything separated from `NSDate`.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
NSInteger currentMonth = [components month]; // this will give you the integer for the month number

[components setMonth:1];
NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
NSDateComponents *nextComponents = [gregorian components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:newDate];
```

**UPDATED:**

```
NSInteger nextMonth = [nextComponents month]; // this will give you the integer for the month number
```

and as @Prince said you can get the name of the month from `NSDateFormatter`. Anyway I repeat to make you understand.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *currentMonthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(currentMonth-1)];
NSString *nextMonthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(nextMonth-1)];

[segMonth setTitle:currentMonthName forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segMonth setTitle:nextMonthName forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: I have implemented your code and it seems to work, however, I tried changing the date on my phone to test. I changed it to June, the first segment correctly changes to june however the second segment still says January....

Comment: I get also 'Unused variable 'nextComponents'

Comment: @Jack I have updated the code and added text "UPDATED" before the updated line.. check now

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in a string formatter and expecting it contain the name of the month. Try

```
[segMonth setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str1] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segMonth setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str2] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

str1 and str2 should be the strings containing the name of the month (obtainable via NSDateFormatter).

Answer (score 1):

Get monthname from number like this:

```
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 NSString *monthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(yourMonthNumberHere-1)];
```

Now use it:

```
 [segMonth setTitle:monthName forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int currentMonth = 12;   //December
int nextMonth = 1;   //January
NSDateFormatter *df1 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *currentMonthName = [[df1 monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(currentMonth-1)];

NSDateFormatter *df2 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *nextMonthName = [[df2 monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(nextMonth-1)];

[segMonth setTitle:currentMonthName forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[segMonth setTitle:nextMonthName forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Note that you'll need to subtract 1 from your currentMonth and nextMonth (which is from 1 - 12) since monthSymbols is zero-based.

Comment: this is just a demonstration, you have to take the month values dynamically.