# Getting the month in DateComponents in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate

I would like to get the month from DateComponents.

My code looks like this:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
NSString *month = [NSString *stringWithFormat:@"%i",dateComponents.month];
```

But this month is an integer, I would like to the month to be in the format of mm or for example: November.

How do i do it?

Comment: please check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488373/ios-how-to-get-a-proper-month-name-from-a-number

Answer (score 0):

```
int monthNumber = 11; 
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *monthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:(monthNumber-1)];//because dateformatter is zero-based
```