# How to get all months of a year in a list

Tags: iphone, ios

How to get all months of a year in a list for UITableView. I want to get all the months of a year in an array so that i cxan display that in table view. I did this way for getting date of a week.

```
 NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];// Init calendar
NSDateComponents* comps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSWeekCalendarUnit|NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate: date]; // Get necessary date components

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd"];
// Week days change from 1 to 7, Sunday is the 1st, Saturday - the last one.
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++){
    [comps setWeekday:i];
    NSDate *tDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    // NSString *day=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:tDate];
    [self.mArrDates addObject:tDate];

}
NSLog(@"dates for week%@", self.mArrDates);
```

Comment: What does that code have to do with an array of month (names presumably)?

Comment: do you want months or weeks?

Comment: @Wain that code i used for displaying dates of a week. imentioned that in question.

Comment: Ok, but what do you want. Month names? Month numbers? What order? Relative to what? How is `@[ @"Jan", @"Feb", ...];` not correct?

Comment: 12 Months of a year are fixed (hardcode them) :)

Comment: @Wain January 2013 and so on all months.

Comment: @Randeep Please update your question with these details. Your question is not clear that you want "MMMM, yyyy".

Comment: @Randeep: One remark concerning your weekdays code in the question: There are regions where Monday counts as the first day in the week (e.g. in Germany).

Comment: You wrote 10 lines of code which you could have easily done with one line of hard coded month names? Seriously?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS: How to get a proper Month name from a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488373/ios-how-to-get-a-proper-month-name-from-a-number)

Answer (score 3):

Just use this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
myArray = [df monthSymbols];
```

You can also use:

```
– shortMonthSymbols
– veryShortMonthSymbols
– shortStandaloneMonthSymbols
```

Find all the information here:

[NSdateFormatter Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To get the current year, use this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString *yearString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[formatter release];
```

If you want another year, just use a different NSDate.

Comment: Why do we require to run a loop here?
NSDateFormatter returns the month symbols in an array
- (NSArray *)monthSymbols
why cant we simply create a reference to this array?

Comment: @AntonioMG That's right man but i required current year also, if i need just names then i could use statically also by putting names in to array. ex: January 2013.