# How to get all months of a year in particular format

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can i get all the months of a year in a table view in this particular format "January 2013" and so on. I need to set the starting month also. Below is the code i tried.

```
int mCurrentMonth = [dateComponents month];
int mCurrentYear = [dateComponents year];

NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",mCurrentMonth];

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:myDate];
NSString *mon = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d",stringFromDate, mCurrentYear];
NSLog(@"month:%@", mon);
```

Above code is giving me only current month in required format. 
Other way i tried is this

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    NSString *monthName = [[df monthSymbols] objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"months name:%@", monthName);
}
```

This way i am getting all months name but not with year. I am not getting how to achieve the desired output that is January 2013 February 2013 and so on.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of your last question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448728/how-to-get-all-months-of-a-year-in-a-list

Comment: @maddy Ya i asked question again because i didn't got answer there.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than reposting. See [How can I get extra attention for my question when I don't have enough rep for a bounty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181499)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
  NSDateFormatter  *dateFormatter   = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    NSDate           *today           = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar       *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *yearComponents  = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  fromDate:today];
    int currentYear  = [yearComponents year];
    for(int months = 0; months < 12; months++)
        NSLog(@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols]objectAtIndex: months],currentYear);
```

output will be :

January 2013

February 2013

March 2013

April 2013

May 2013

June 2013

July 2013

August 2013

September 2013

October 2013

November 2013

December 2013

Edited : For Above output from current month Use following code :

```
 NSDateFormatter  *dateFormatter   = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    NSDate           *today           = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar       *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *yearComponents  = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit |    NSMonthCalendarUnit  fromDate:today];
    int currentYear  = [yearComponents year];
    int currentmonth=[yearComponents month];
    NSLog(@"current Month %d",currentmonth);
    for(int months = currentmonth - 1; months < 12; months++)
        NSLog(@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols]objectAtIndex: months],currentYear);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahesh this is the most simple solution and easy solution. I need to ask one more thing that if i want to start from current month.

Comment: I need to ask one more thing in above, can you guide for that.

Comment: @Randeep : Sure bro if i'll have solution for your issue i'll definately guide you. :)

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546905/compare-dates-of-a-month-with-an-array/17547038?noredirect=1#17547038

Comment: I want to get last one year month from current month.  ?

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let today = Date()
let currentCalendar = Calendar.current
var yearComponents: DateComponents? = currentCalendar.dateComponents([.year], from: today)
let currentYear = Int(yearComponents!.year!)
for months in 0..<12 {
    print("\(dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols[months]) \(currentYear)")
}
```

Output:

```
Jan 2017
Feb 2017
Mar 2017
Apr 2017
May 2017
Jun 2017
Jul 2017
Aug 2017
Sep 2017
Oct 2017
Nov 2017
Dec 2017
```

Answer (score 3):

please try this code this may help you

```
NSDateFormatter  *dateFormatter   = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate           *today           = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar       *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *monthComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
int currentMonth = [monthComponents month];

NSDateComponents *yearComponents  = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  fromDate:today];
int currentYear  = [yearComponents year];
int nextYear     = currentYear + 1;

int months  = 1;
int year;
for(int m = currentMonth; months < 12; m++){

    int nextMonth = m % 12;

    if(nextMonth < currentMonth){
        year = nextYear;
    } else {
        year = currentYear;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols] objectAtIndex: nextMonth],year);

    months++;
```

add no of year in current year  that you want in range. i hope this will help you

**Modify Code**

Month Start From January For that you can set date that you want to start form in calendar component here set "30/01/2013"

```
NSDate *dateStart= [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"30/01/2013"];
NSDateComponents *monthComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:dateStart]
```

Please use this code that would start moth form  **January**

```
 NSDateFormatter  *dateFormatter   = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yyyy"];
NSDate           *dateStart           = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"30/01/2013"];
NSCalendar       *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *monthComponents = [currentCalendar components:NSMonthCalendarUnit fromDate:dateStart];
int currentMonth = [monthComponents month];

NSDateComponents *yearComponents  = [currentCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit  fromDate:dateStart];
int currentYear  = [yearComponents year];

int months  = 1;
int nextMonth=0;
int year;

    for(int m = currentMonth; months < 13; m++){
    year = currentYear;
   NSLog(@"%@ %i",[[dateFormatter monthSymbols] objectAtIndex: nextMonth],year);
    nextMonth =m % 12;
    if(nextMonth <= currentMonth ){
        year = currentYear+1;

    }       
    months++;
        if(months>12){
            months=1;
            currentYear++;
        }

  }
```

Comment: This is starting from current month i need  from starting of year january.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSInteger startingMonth = 1;
NSInteger startingYear = 2013;

// we'll need this in several places
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// build the first date (in the starting month and year)
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setMonth:startingMonth];
[comps setYear:startingYear];
[comps setDay:1];
NSDate *date = [cal dateFromComponents:comps];

// this is our output format
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM YYYY"];

// we need NSDateComponents for the difference, i.e. at each step we
// want to go one month further
NSDateComponents *comps2 = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps2 setMonth:1];

for (int = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    NSLog("%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);

    // add 1 month to date
    date = [cal dateByAddingComponents:comps2 toDate:date options:0];
}

[comps2 release];
[fomatter release];
[comps release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

int year=2010,month=5;
[components setYear:year];
[components setMonth:month];
NSDate *help = [[NSDate alloc]init];
help = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];


NSString *dateStr =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",help];
NSDateFormatter *dtF = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dtF setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSDate *dt = [dtF dateFromString:dateStr];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatStr = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatStr setDateFormat:@"MMMM-yyyy"];
NSString *strDate = [dateFormatStr stringFromDate:dt];

NSLog(@"%@",strDate);

         OR
```

//in your code keep all code in for loop and set month as you need to.

```
[components setYear:year];
[components setMonth:month];
```

I did it for one month, you can put it in loop. Hope it helps.

Comment: Instead of getting the date string and then parsing that into an NSDate, use [calendar dateFromComponents:components];