# Compare dates of a month with an array

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app i am showing, the list of months in table view. For each month there are few events in it for some dates. So my question is how to compare the dates in my array with the dates of month to show the events in their respective months only.

Comment: what you have tried ?? please show some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NSDateComponents` for that:

```
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = 
      [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:yourDate];

[components month];// gives you month
```

Compare this month with the Array index for example or another way you prefer.

Comment: don't forget to also compare the year (not just the month) or you will be seeing events from jan '11 with jan '12.

Answer (score 0):

In your case probably you only need to compare the year and month component of the date.
There's probably many ways for implementing this.
This is what i would have tried. Convert your date in tableview in yyyy-MM Format and also the event dates in the same format probably the way given below.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM"];
dateFormatter1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSDate *monthDate=[NSDate date];
NSString *strMonthDate=[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:monthDate];
NSLog(@"%@",strMonthDate);
```

Compare this monthDate string with your eventDate string using normal NSString comparison methods.

Comment: This is the format of date in array 2013-07-23 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: Use above listed code just replace monthDate with your own date in array(Make sure its instance of NSDate) u'll get o/p 2013-07 as a string.