# Can not get month short symbols with @"MMM"

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I looked at [iOS: How to get a proper Month name from a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488373/ios-how-to-get-a-proper-month-name-from-a-number), and [formatting options](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/29/nsdateformatter-formatting/), but still my result is incorrect

My code looks like

```
+ (NSString *)getMonthName:(NSInteger)monthNumber {
    if (monthNumber == 0) {
        return @"";
    }
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
    NSString *monthName = [formatter monthSymbols][(NSUInteger) (monthNumber - 1)];
    NSLog(@"monthNumber-%d, monthName-%@", monthNumber, monthName);
    return monthName;
}
```

and it gets called as

```
self.monthHeaderLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Helper getMonthName:self.transactionsModel.month]];
```

When I run my application, I see log as

```
2015-01-10 13:02:17.577 myapp-ios[19175:60b] monthNumber-1, monthName-January
```

Why is it still incorrect? what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `monthSymbols` and `setDateFormat:` have nothing to do with each other. Why not use `shortMonthSymbols`?

Comment: those are the available month symbols you can use: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-SW39

Answer (score 0):

As per @rmaddy's comment, this is all I had to do

```
NSString *monthName = [formatter shortMonthSymbols][(NSUInteger) (monthNumber - 1)];
```

and it worked out fine

```
2015-01-10 13:23:02.223 myapp-ios[19183:60b] monthNumber-1, monthName-Jan
```

Comment: BTW - there is no need to cast the result of `monthNumber - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **shortMonthSymbols** instead of **monthSymbols**

```
+ (NSString *)getMonthName:(NSInteger)monthNumber {
    if (monthNumber == 0) {
        return @"";
    }
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

NSString *monthName = [formatter shortMonthSymbols][(NSUInteger) (monthNumber - 1)];
NSLog(@"monthNumber-%d, monthName-%@", monthNumber, monthName);
    return monthName;
}
```